# Brightness issue ASUS Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel, asus, brightness, amd-graphics

first of all i tried everything i found on internet and didn't get any result.

I have an ASUS Vivobook with AMD RADEON Graphics and I can not adjust the brightness on my laptop, neither with FN keys nor on settings.

The only thing that I have read about but couldn't do is upgrade my kernel. (I did it 2ice but I couldn't boot Ubuntu with the new Kernel).

Did anyone have the same issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you try to upgrade kernel?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade

Comment: It seems you did something wrong. Run `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge` and reboot.

Comment: I did it but now it will not start. All I see is the main asus screen. I manually shuted down the laptop and run recovery mode. The kernel is upgraded but the brightmess issue is still there. I rebooted and the asus main screen is there again

Comment: Try adjusting the brightness by using this method: https://askubuntu.com/a/953447/300458 . It was very useful for me. (For a laptop, you probably need to choose something like "DP1", "EDP1" or "LVDS1").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10 which have kernel 5.8. This might was the problem. Everything works just fine! As I was told on another topic, kernel 5.8 will be available for 20.04 in a few months. Be patience! Or find a way to upgrade your kernel, I could't without issues.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (and it is really simple ;-D) was to update the kernel, like in this: https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/ where there are three different methods to do it. Choose what you want. Also, before you install the new kernel, I first reset the grub to its initial values, and then reinstalled it. Thanks to the guy from the cited website. (my machine: ubuntu 20.04, ASUS VivoBook AMD Ryzen7 Radeon, Realtek 8821 wifi, seems to work also for ubuntu 19.04 in another laptop)