# Ubuntu 22.04 laptop brightness keys not working

Tags: nvidia, graphics, lenovo, brightness, monitor

I have a Lenovo Legion 7 laptop with Nvidia RTX 2070 GPU and the brightness keys on the laptop do not change the brightness at all (it stays on max brightness it seems). I tried adding some parameters to grub settings that I found online but nothing seems to work so far.

```
Model: Lenovo Lenovo Legion 7 15IMH05
Memory: 32GB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12
Graphics: NVIDIA Corporation TU106BM [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile]
Disk Capacity: 2.0 TB

OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
GNOME: 42.2
Windowing System: X11
```

Comment: Look around here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/894465/changing-the-screen-brightness-of-the-external-screen
especially around the  "Hardware control solution". Try to make it work from the command line first. You have more chance to debug there...

Answer (score 0):

I was partially able to solve this by creating a small shell script. It turns out that the the actual brightness is stored in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness` but for some reason the keys do not update the monitor brightness.

So I listen to the actual brightness using `inotify` and then I use `xrandr` to set the brightness for my laptop monitor (`DP-4`). You can find out what monitors you have connected using `xrandr --current`

You might want to tweak the math a little but other than that it seems to be working.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  inotifywait -e modify /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness
  
  read -r max < /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
  read -r actual < /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness
  
  # Will give .x brightness
  brightness=`echo "scale=1; 100/$max*$actual/100" | bc`
  
  xrandr --output DP-4 --brightness $brightness
done
```

Comment: Note that `xrandr --brightness` this doesn't adjust the backlight, so wont save any power.  It adjusts the intensity of the colour the display pixels produce

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for my Lenovo laptop with NVIDIA RTX A2000 GPU: [How to find an NVIDIA driver which works with your brightness function buttons](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446675/327339).

Basically, you just need to install the latest-possible NVIDIA driver which doesn't have brightness-button bugs/regressions. I explain the full process in great detail.